# Syncing Google Sheets to Calendar App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have the below script and keep getting the error 'Cannot find method createEvent(number,string,string).' I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var complete = "Done";

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var aname = row[2]; //Agent
    var cname = row[3]; //Client Name
    var country = row[4]; //Client Country
    var phone = row[5]; //Phone Number
    var deposit = row[6]; //Type of Deposit
    var ewallet = row[7]; //Processor/eWallet
    var method = row[8]; //Deposit Method
    var amount = row[9]; //Amount/Percent
    var date = new Date(row[10]);  //Date of Next Contact
    var target = row[12]; //Target Amount
    var history = row[13]; //Deposit History incl. dates
    var currency = row[14]; //Currency
    var comments = row[15]; //Comments
    var stime = new Date (row[17]);
    var etime = new Date (row[18]);
    var added = row[19]; //Added to calendar

      if (added != complete) {
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
      var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(cname, stime, etime);

      currentCell.setValue(complete)};
}
}
```

Comment: Check your variables `starttime` and `endtime`, seems to me like they're being treated as strings because of your use of the `+` operator. These need to be dates for them to work with `createEvent()`.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that it cannot find that method, probably because you're using wrong arguments to the function `createEvent(String,Date,Date)` (see documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date))).

You are using function `createEvent(number,String,String)`, which doesn't exist.

Your first variable `cname` should be transformed to string, and what you are also seing in the error is that 2nd and 3rd parameter are as string, while they should be dates.
The proper solution would be to transform `starttime` and `endtime` to date, and that depends on how is the format of your string date.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it, and it doesn't throw up any errors now. However, it currently doesn't create the event in the calendar, but it does update the sheet to say 'Done'. The code above has been amended to reflect the changes.